# Open Image Sequence in QuickTime from Command Line

Tags: command-line, quicktime

You can open a video in QuickTime from the terminal with `open video.mov`, but is there a way to do that with an image sequence?

The only way I know how is to open QuickTime, hit cancel on the open popup, and then File > Open Image Sequence. Doing it from terminal would make my workflow easier.

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running? I'm asking because when I open **QuickTime Player** from the **UI** or _command line_, without passing it arguments, I do not get anything that needs to be canceled. That said I did try `open -a "QuickTime Player" "/path/to/Image Sequence"`, however, the **Resolution:** _pop-up menu_ was empty and effectively inactive. Might that be what "hit cancel on the open popup" you were referring to?

Comment: Anyway, I can write a _shell script_ using **AppleScript** and **UI Scripting** that would take the `"/path/to/Image Sequence"` as an argument and get to a working _dialog box_, if that's something you are interested in. let me know.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the suggestions. Opening image sequences from CLI was just a convenience thing, so I'll pass on the offer. But, I appreciate it. I'll have to look into AppleScript, I'm more accustomed to Linux and wasn't aware that was a thing.